# FTP - Use multiple directories to appears as one

Tags: windows-10, ftp, filezilla, network-drive

I wanted to setup a FTP server on my Win10 PC that I use as a server. So, I chose FileZilla server. However is it possible to share a folder that contains multiple directories from multiple drives ?

For example I have a folder named Movies on both my E:, F: and G: and I'd like them to just list as one folder named Movies for people who connect to the server. The only thing I found with Filezilla is using alias, but they appear as 3 separate folders named Movies, Movies and Movies.

So I would like that all the subfolders on each drive gets merged into a virtual "main" folder called Movies.

Thanks in advance,

and I am willing to use drop filezilla and use other software if necessary.

Comment: I'll delete my answer as it isn't what you really wanted

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that any ready-made FTP server will allow you do such specific configuration.

You would have to implement your own FTP server.

If SFTP is ok (I would recommend it over FTP), the [Apache Mina SFTP server project](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/) is built on top a virtual file system API, that will allow you to relatively easily build a file system that matches your requirements.